# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported error for $http.post call from angular

Tags: angularjs, http, spring-mvc

I am trying to update some data using $http.post method from angularjs to Spring MVC controller. But I get error as "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported". My code snippets are as below :

//AngularJS Service

```
updateData : function(data) {
    return $http.post('updateData', data).then(
               function(response){
                 // success callback
                 return response;
               }, 
               function(response){
                 // failure callback
                 return response;
               }
    );
}
```

where data is as below :

data = [{
        id: 1, 
        name: 'foo'
}, {
        id: 2, 
        name: 'bar'
},{
        id: 3,
        name: 'baz'
}];

//Spring MVC controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateData(@RequestBody Company company) throws Exception {
    // I have created POJO for company with id and name getter-setter
    // logic to update the data in db
    //System.out.println(company.getName());
    return "success";       
}
```

Any error in my code?

Comment: I'd add a `/` in front of 'updateData' in you JS code and check via F12 networking tab, to which URL the request is actually sent. Your Java Code looks good and hence should work as expected.

Comment: ok - let me try that

Comment: No .... adding / in front of updateData gives me 404 error.

Comment: It can be done using POST too..are you sending your data properly same as it is expecting at Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is an array format `data = [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' },{ id: 3, name: 'baz' }];`. But your @RequestBody  having only object. Your RequestBody  should be a List. Then only it can accept

So Kindly change your code from `@RequestBody Company company` to `@RequestBody List<Company> company`. then let me know